How to add special characters to the toolbar in CRAFT CMS in CKEditor?
I use CRAFT CMS 5. I have installed the CKEDITOR plugin for text fields. I can't figure out how to extend the basic toolbar by adding the ability to select special characters.
Please tell me how to figure it out for a beginner))
